# How to remove comma for input number in dynamic table new row

Tags: html, jquery

I want my added dynamic row have the same function with my first row which can remove the comma. My first row works pretty well. The problems is the **.replace(/,/g, '')** in added row.

When I add **.replace(/,/g, '')** into my add row function, it shows me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`.

```
html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
html += '<td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
```

If I change **.replace(/,/g, '')** to **.replace(/,/g, "")**, it shows me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

```
html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, "")));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
html += '<td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, "")));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
```

I insert the same amount for row 1 and row 2 but my result for row 2 should same as row 1.

My current result:

```
   Qty   |    Price
6,000.00 | 1,234,567.00
  6.00   |    1.00
```

My expected result:

```
   Qty   |    Price
6,000.00 | 1,234,567.00
6,000.00 | 1,234,567.00
```

```js
function currencyFormat(num) {
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return "";
  }
  return num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

function onlyDecimal(ControlId) {
  $(ControlId).on('keyup', function(key) {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '')) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '');
    }
  })
};
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(e) {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>'
  html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';
  html += '</tr>'

  $('.table').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>
      <td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<a id="addRow" href="javascript:; "><i class="fe fe-plus-circle mr-1"></i>Add</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `` character for your `HTML` like this:

```
html += `<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>`;
```

Here is working sample

```js
function currencyFormat(num) {
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return "";
  }
  return num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

function onlyDecimal(ControlId) {
  $(ControlId).on('keyup', function(key) {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '')) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '');
    }
  })
};
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(e) {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>'
  html += `<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>`;
  html += `<td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>`;
  html += '</tr>'

  $('.table').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>
      <td><input class="price" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, '')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<a id="addRow" href="javascript:; "><i class="fe fe-plus-circle mr-1"></i>Add</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I wanna ask is there any another way to call the function? Because your answer is only applicable in client side, server side still thrown error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.` when I get data. Backtick can't use in server side.

Comment: Anyway try this one: `html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ' + '' + ')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>';`

Comment: Because I have two web page. One is for add and another is for update. The html is used in add page and in update page, when I get the data from database and I want to show in the table. I was writing this code in code behind which is Update.aspx.cs. This is  [My Current Code](https://i.postimg.cc/GmZsB5yr/result1.png), however it show me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.` when I key in the amount.

Comment: Have you tried another thing I wrote in previous comment? This one I mean.  `html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" onblur="this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ' + '' + ')));" onkeyup="onlyDecimal(this)"></td>'`

Comment: Already tried, but still can't, `+ ' '+ ` when I put this, it said empty character literal

Comment: `sList += "<td><input class='qty' type='text' onblur='this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, " + "''" + ")));' onkeyup='onlyDecimal(this)' value='" + dr["ItemQty"].ToString() + "'></td>";` if I use this, it said `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.` and if I use your latest code `sList += "<td><input class='qty' type='text' onblur='this.value=currencyFormat(parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, " + '' + ")));' onkeyup='onlyDecimal(this)' value='" + dr["ItemQty"].ToString() + "'></td>";` it said empty character literal before I start debug.